# Can't reach WordPress installation after changing IP address for domain

Tags: domain, wordpress, web-hosting

I had a WordPress site located on a VPS, say the VPS's IP is 192.168.0.1.

At Namesilo I bought, for example `www.example.com`, and bound it to 192.168.0.1.

A few days ago my old IP – 192.168.0.1 – wasn't available anymore, so I changed it to `192.168.0.2`, and went to Namesilo to change my domain's corresponding IP to the new one `192.168.0.2`.

When I open a browser and type `www.example.com` like before, I can't open my WordPress site.

What do I have to do?

PS: my web service is apache2.0 on centos 6 ,  when I open

```
http://192.168.0.2/wordpress/index.php
```

it works

but if I open  `http://www.example.com`

in apache's  `access_log` , it show

```
5.188.210.31 - - [03/Jun/2019:10:44:19 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 4961 "http://www.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Usually you don't have to do anything. But your question is very unclear. What web server are you using? How have you configured it? What error do you get? Does the domain resolve to the correct IP address? Does your web server register the client trying to access the website? (Check the server logs.)

Comment: "I change it to 192.168.0.2"  How did you change the IP?  Where did you get the new IP from?

Comment: hello slhck , i have change my topic for more clear ,  for this question : Does the domain resolve to the correct IP address?   I think maybe it is the reason why I can not visit my worpress , but I do not know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching about this on internet, i found the following useful information:

https://magicpress.net/documentation/dns/how-to-configure-dns-for-your-domain-name-on-namesilo/

I read that there Will be 24-48 hours of DNS propagation during which your website may not be available.

Comment: yes , seems is propagation  problem , now it can be visit normally

Answer (score 0):

If it's the propagation you're waiting on .. 
Next time a few days ahead of time, change your DNS TTL to a lower number 3600 is popular.. then your change will be almost instant.

Also highly recommend using a 3rd party DNS service like Cloudflare! then you can move servers and IPs really simply and quickly when needed, also speeds up sites!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, it was not related to IP address propagation. The root cause for me was that the original WP installation had the old IP address in its configuration.

I am using WP v6.2 using a MySQL DB.

The table in question is called `wordpress.wp_options`.

I ran this update using MySQL Workbench and the issue was fixed:

```
update wordpress.wp_options 
set option_value='http://[ENTER NEW IP HERE]' 
where option_name = 'siteurl' or option_name = 'home'
```

(Two rows should update)

BTW, I started using its full domain name instead of IP address so that future IP address changes should not affect WP anymore.